# Permissions in Bluefish HTML editor

Tags: html

I am new to Linux, just installed Fedora 13 and am trying to teach myself LAMP. I installed the Bluefish editor and when I try to save the file, I receive the following error:

`Could not save file script1.php
  Error opening file '/var/www/html/script1.php':
  Permission denied`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to give your user write permissions to the  /var/www/html directory.  You could do this on a file by file basis, but if you're the only one modifying the files then the easiest way is make yourself the owner of the directory.

Comment: Thank you. For my edification, would I need to change the permissions for each directory, e.g. '/var', '/var/www',... or just the last one? I guess I am asking what the best practice is. Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure what the "best" practice is, but for me this works: chown -R myuserid /var/www/html  If you've got multiple userids with data under html then you'll need to go down to the first directory for which you have personal ownership.