# "Could not rename" error in Bluefish editor on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, bluefish

I'm trying to use Bluefish 2.2.7 on Mac OS X 10.9.5 to rename the file `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/index.php`.  I navigate to the file in Bluefish, right click on it, select rename, and make the change.  An error message then pops up, saying

```
Could not rename
file:///Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/index.php
```

and of course the file name does not change. [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/187406/permissions-in-bluefish-html-editor) is basically the same question for Linux, but I wasn't sure how to apply that to a Mac.

So what can I do to be able to rename this file in Bluefish?

Comment: In order to rename a file, you need to have write permission to the directory holding the file in question, because technically renaming a file is a modification of its parent directory. Do you have that permission?

Comment: The user I'm on is an admin user.  Is there something I need to do in addition to that to get permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with one way to get rid of the error:

1. Make sure you're on an admin user.
2. Select the XAMPP folder.
3. Select File > Get Info.
4. Make sure the permissions say system: read and write, admin: read and write, everyone: read only.
5. From the gear menu at the bottom, select "Apply to enclosed items..." and wait while it applies those permissions to all subfolders and items in the subfolders.

Then try to change the name in Bluefish and it should work.  It seems the default in the XAMPP folders is that the admin does not have write permission, and this will remedy that.